# Some Pemalink problems, probably caused by wrong .htaccess configuration?

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, wp-redirect

I have import on my local webserver a backup of a website made using WordPress but I am finding some difficulties with **PermaLink** configuration

The main problem is that if I use the permalink setted as Article Name I can see the homepage but if I click on the articles links into the homepage (to see the article) I always obtain the following message error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
>   /wordpress35/2012/10/11/se-milano-avesse-il-mare-anzi-no-la-montagna-di-campiglio/
>   was not found on this server.

If I instead I use the Default settings for permalink (`http://localhost/wordpress35/?p=123`) I have no problem and I can access to the articles in my website

I think that this is a **.htaccess** problem. Can you help me to create an **.htaccess** file that solve this problem?

This is my actual **.htaccess** file content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I need to use the URL format described as: `http://localhost/wordpress35/my-article-name`

Comment: See [the Codex page on `.htaccess`](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) for the default WordPress `.htaccess` rules.

Comment: mmm I have put a .htaccess file taking the code fromt the codex page but still no work, I have insert the code in the origina edited post

Comment: does your server have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: yes, infact: andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~$ sudo a2enmod rewriteModule rewrite already enabled

Comment: is your .htaccess file being parsed by the server? you're getting your server's 404 document, when you should be getting a WordPress 404 if the permalink structure is incorrect, which seems to indicate that your .htaccess file is being ignored entirely.

Comment: and what can I do to discover if my .htaccess is parsed from my server?

Comment: you can type some nonsense on the first line of your .htaccess file, and if it's being read it'll generate a 500 internal server error.

Comment: After putting a nonsense string at the beginning of my .htaccess file I obtain the 500 Internal Server Error
I have no idea :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to look into who the owner is of the folders as well as permissions. I've just recently completed setting up multiple WP sites on a local Ubuntu server & the majority of issues I ran into were permissions related.

WordPress documentation for permissions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions